# Programmatically create Google Apps Domain

Tags: java, python, google-app-engine

I am currently working on a project that involves the google apps provisioning api.
Without getting too detailed about the purpose or inner workings of the project, I would like to ask a very simple question:
Is there a way to programmatically create a google apps for business domain (especially as a reseller)?
After tooling around the provisioning api for a while all i could find are ways to add and remove users but nothing pertaining to whole domains.

Comment: I think that for security measures, google doesn't allow to create domains manually.

Comment: As a reseller when you provision domains you pay for them, so the security risk is minimal (unless you have very rich pirates). And the verification is as simple as changing a dns entry or adding a key-sig file to your domains root http server. Both tasks very easily automated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an API only available to Google Apps Resellers, if you are one of them you should get access to it.

Comment: Thanks, currently in approval process, so i can't just yet.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if what you're trying to do is possible, but there are lots of APIs for Google Apps stuff. This may be of some use:

> The Provisioning API provides a
>   mechanism to programmatically create
>   and manage Google Apps user accounts
>   with one or more domains, nicknames,
>   email aliases,organization units, and
>   groups. Using this API you can
>   minimize disruption to your
>   organization's current processes by
>   synchronizing user data between Google
>   Apps and your existing user management
>   system.

More info here:

http://code.google.com/googleapps/docs/#domain